# How can I timeout a task, but log how long the task actually took?

Tags: .net, web-services, task-parallel-library

I have a third party web service that I make requests against. If a request takes longer than 6 seconds I give up on the result.

What I'd like to do is make the service call, if it takes more than 6 seconds timeout and return, but when the service call actually returns a result, or the underlying connection times out I'd like to log how long the call would have taken.

The motivation is that I currently time out at 6 seconds and I know that a percentage of calls timeout. What I'd like to have is some data on how long calls typically take, even the ones past 6 seconds. It might be that if I increase my timeout to 7 seconds then I would timeout much less often, but without data I don't know.

I'm working in C#, is there something that I can do with `Task<T>` or will I have to build something more bespoke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be:

- first, ContinueWith on the task to do the log
- then, use Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay) for timeout